# LIMIT e OFFSET duplica dados no mysql

Tags: mysql, select-limit, offset

Tenho uma tabela no mysql mas ao utilizar LIMIT e OFFSET tenho um retorno indesejado, 1 dado se repete a cada busca.

Olhem a tabela:

[image: tabela]

uso então o seguinte comando:

```
SELECT funcionario.nome
FROM funcionario
LIMIT 0, 2
```

me retorna:
[image: busca 1]

após o segundo comando:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `funcionario`
LIMIT 1,2
```

tenho o retorno: [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**como fazer esse tipo de consulta sem repetir dados ?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O `LIMIT` você coloca de qual linha ele inicia até a linha que ele termina, ou o número limite de linhas, por exemplo:

Se você colocar `LIMIT 1`, ele vai puxar a primeira linha, no seu caso o funcionário `abner`. `LIMIT 2`: Duas linhas (os funcionários `Abner` e `g`) e por ai vai.

`LIMIT 1, 2` vai trazer duas linhas iniciando da linha `1`. No caso do seu exemplo, vai trazer iniciando do `g`, até a segunda linha `teste`, assim.
Se colocar `LIMIT 2, 2`. Ele vai trazer duas linhas iniciando da linha `2`, nesse caso, irá vir os funcionários `teste` e `joao`.

No seu exemplo, o ideal é usar `LIMIT 0, 2`, `LIMIT 2, 2`, `LIMIT 4,2` e por aí vai...

Answer (score -1):

LIMIT e OFFSET não fazem dados se repetirem.
Na imagem não vejo dados repetidos. 
Para não mostrar valor duplicados usa se DISTINCT.

SELECT **DISTINCT** funcionario.nome
FROM funcionario
LIMIT 0, 2